# using vb6 for testing

Tags: testing, vb6

A friend has got an interview for a testing job. Apparently the job requires knowledge of VB6. My friend knows VB6 and she knows testing, but she and I are both wondering what is the relevance of VB6 to testing.

Is there some well-known standard way to test applications using VB6 that my friend should learn for this interview?

Comment: @codeModuler I have edited to try to make the question clearer, I hope I haven't misunderstood. Please edit it again if you like. @Anonymous close voter - care to explain why you think it should be closed? IMHO it's a reasonable question.

Answer (score 0):

*As Far As I Know* there is no standard knowledge about using VB6 to test that your friend is expected to know. If your friend knows testing, and she knows VB6, she should be fine. I'd guess the employer has a special testing method they've invented themselves, and they wouldn't expect the interview candidates to know it in advance. (*I could be wrong*: we'll see whether anyone else answers this question.)

I did find a book [Visual Basic 6 for Testers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1893115534) published in 2001. You can view the table of contents on Amazon. The topics sound a bit wacky - writing unit tests for COM objects through VB6 code, testing databases to see data is valid, checking registry entries are valid with VB6 scripts. I don't *think* these became standard approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You might also check HP Quick Test Pro, it uses VBscript for scripts.